# Any existing services for upload a huge video file (~5gb) via browser?

Tags: php, file, http, video, upload

My client having a requirement that need to upload huge video files (e.g. 5GB) to his own server via browser, need have progress bar and pause/resume would be even better.

Wondering if there's any existing services (paid or not) for doing such a thing. Also any technique that I might able to implement this by myself. I've seen Vimeo allows user upload huge file by HTTP, not sure how they make it.

Currently I'm using JAVA FTP applet but it really slow and not that stable if transferring time is hours (e.g. I got socket exception, peer reset). So really keen to seek some more stable and lightweighted solution

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

In order to upload such large files with a browser, you can use SWFUpload and the native HTML4 method and if the user selects a large file, he is prompted to click on a button to toggle the native uploader. In Webkit, Firefox and IE8 that seems to work great for files in the 10+ gigabyte range.

Remember Youtube runs on Googles custom server software.

Comment: Are you sure, those browsers handle uploads of 10+ gigable correctly? From what I have experienced none of them work in Windows, Chrome at least does in Linux...